# What are "fanned ginger snaps"?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

Katy Butler's *Knocking on Heaven's Door: The Path to a Better Way of Death* (2013) includes [this passage](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249):

> I remembered her attentively setting out thin white bone china cups for my father and me, and a white plate holding **six fanned ginger snaps**. I remember how, no matter how bady things were going, we'd gather each day at the kitchen table— waiting as the tea steeped, enjoying one another, and simply being alive.

I think I know *ginger snap*, which is a kind of cookie with ginger in it. But what are *fanned* ginger snaps?

Answer (score 1):

*Fanned* here refers to the arrangement of the ginger snaps.

I would describe these stroopwafels as *fanned* or *fanned out*:

[image: Morguefile image of fanned stroopwafels by MaxStraeten http://mrg.bz/Losq0M]

This is not a definition that learner's dictionaries seem to have, but the general Oxford Dictionaries website offers an [applicable verb meaning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fan?q=fanned#fan__23):

> Spread out or cause to spread out into a semicircular shape
>
> > [NO OBJECT]: a dress made of tiny pleats that fanned out as she walked

So the ginger snaps have been laid out on the white plate, flat but overlapping, presumably in a curve to follow the edge of the plate. The *fan* shape is found both in the circular arrangement of the cookies (the British would call them *biscuits*) and in their overlapping edges; the regular pattern of ridges is evocative of the pleats of a hand fan.

An image search can be helpful in visualizing such things, especially because the better stock image websites offer well-detailed descriptions. Searching on "fanned cookies" turned up suitable sample images for [chocolate wafer cookies fanned out](http://www.istockphoto.com/photo/chocolate-wafer-cookies-fanned-out-on-a-white-background-gm122180444-11644319), [cookies fanned out](http://www.123rf.com/photo_48834590_cookies-crackers-fanned-out-on-a-white-background.html), and [sweet biscuits fanned out](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-four-rows-of-sweet-biscuits-fanned-out-90650780.html).

Comment: WTH is a stroopwafel?

Comment: @AlanCarmack The best thing ever.